# Tkinter string callbacks

Tags: python, function, menu, tkinter

Here is the situation:

I have an XML file with the menu hiearchy for my app in it. I can display the menu, but defining the callbacks in the XML file only returns strings.

The more defined problem:
I need a way to callback functions via a string. Yeah, there's the

```
lambda x: pass
```

deal, but I'm not really sure that's what I need.

Comment: What do the strings look like?

Comment: Well, getattr might work, but that would get kind of ugly.

Comment: they are the names of the callback functions: "self.logic.account_new" would be an example.

Comment: So you need to define callback like: `self.logic.account_new = lambda x: <do sth>` ?

Comment: Clarification: Do you want to define functions in XML/strings, or do you want to existing call functions named in XML, or both?

Comment: I would like to call functions that are predefined somewhere else, named in the XML.

Comment: Well, seems like you won't get around `eval` (with validation, of course!) if you don't change that format. Alternatively, a function built around `re.split` and applying `getattr` iteratively - IF it's always plain attribute access. Neither option is very elegant or clean, though. Are you sure you have to go this way?

Comment: Yeah, those were the conclusions I came to, and there was bound to be something unclean about that whole thing because the XML menu deal worked almost flawlessly. Se la vie.

Comment: No, I don't absolutely have to do it this way, as it's a small pet project. Just thought it would be absolutely amazing if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a way to callback functions via a string.

From the comments to your question I understand that you'd like to do something like:

```
# ...
callback_str = getcallback_str() # e.g., 'self.logic.account_new'
callback = eval_dottedname(self, callback_str)`
```

In this case `eval_dottedname()` function could be implemented as:

```
def eval_dottedname(obj, dottedname):
    if dottedname.partition(".")[0] != 'self': # or some other criteria
                                               # to limit the context
        raise ValueError
    return reduce(getattr, dottedname.split('.')[1:], obj)
```

A better approach would be to limit string callbacks to simple identifiers and use a dispatch table like stdlib's [`cmd` module](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd):

```
  def dispatch(self, callback_str):
      return getattr(self, 'do_' + callback_str, self.default)()      

  def do_this(self):
      pass

  def do_that(self):
      pass
```